# foreach loop in mvc razor to iterate each element from the model and display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I want to Display each element on Razor view from Model through foreach loop,I have no code in Controller 
when I run the Application , I get the Error:

> Object reference not set to Instance of an Object

Please some body help me, I wrote the code in the View

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Web.Category>   

@foreach(var item in Model){  
   @item.CategoryName    
}
```

and My Controller is

```
public ActionResult Category(){

    return View();

}
```

Comment: Show us the code from your Controller, what are you passing to the `View`.

Comment: First you fetch categories from dataSource(for example from DB). And pass it to view. OR first you read some tutorial, How MVC framework work?

Comment: How could you expect that to work?

Comment: I have no code in my Controller I just want what code i must write in Controller . can you Please help @Dimitar Dimitorv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean something like this:

```
public ActionResult Category(){

    var categories = db.Categories;

    return View(categories);

}
```

OR

```
 public ActionResult Category(){

    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    categories.Add(new Category() { ID = 1, Name = "Bikes" });
    categories.Add(new Category() { ID = 2, Name = "Cars" });
    categories.Add(new Category() { ID = 3, Name = "Trucks" });

    return View(categories);

}
```

You should initialize your model in controller...

Comment: Thank to all of you I got the Idea that First I need to Pass my Model Category to the Controller Action then i will be able to iterate the eletement and display on the view .

Answer (score 0):

`Model` is null.

If you want to display data from the model, you need to pass a model from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look your view is expecing a `Model`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Web.Category>
```

In your Controller you're not passing anything to the view, so the view has `null` as a Model.
You need to create your collection `IEnumerable<Category>` and pass it to the view.

Comment: @user1711439 You got it, mate :)